# Python. Область видимости переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сразу извините, если решение легкое. Я в этом новичек. 
У меня есть функция, которая должна дополнять с вызовом значение глобальной переменной.
После объявления перменной и присвоения значения, используя перменную в функции ошибка " local variable 'full' referenced before assignment" 
Пробовал несколько вариантов:

```
global full
full = 'test'
def add(user):
    full = full + '{0.first_name}'.format(user)
    return full
ERROR: local variable 'full' referenced before assignment
```

```
global full
full = 'test'
def add(user):
    nonlocal full
    full = full + '{0.first_name}'.format(user)
    return full
ERROR:no binding for nonlocal 'full' found
```

```
full = 'test'
def add(user):
    nonlocal full
    full = full + '{0.first_name}'.format(user)
    return full
ERROR:no binding for nonlocal 'full' found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть-чуть промахнулись)

```py
full = 'test'
def add(user):
    # add не видит full
    global full
    # а теперь видит
    full = full + '{0.first_name}'.format(user)
    # меняет full (так что не обязательно его возвращать следующей строкой)
    return full
```

Ключ. слово global используется внутри блока, чтобы подтянуть переменную из "родительского" неймспейса

Comment: В последнем решении считывалась (не надо global) и изменялась(надо global) глобальная переменная full.Можно было обьявить локальную переменную full_new='<uninitialized'>,считать глобальную full и вернуть локальную full_new.

Comment: @Константин Логика и структура решения на совесть автора) Хоть я и позволил себе комментарий о возврате значения full, я лишь ответил на вопрос об области видимости и инструкции global

Comment: Я просто другим обьясняю про global потому что это мудренная штука)

Comment: @Константин Там все же правильно все, мне надо что бы после каждого вызова функции изменялась глобальная перменная

Comment: Ну да,но заметьте код будет чище если return убрать,тогда сразу все ясно)цель программирования)